# Sibling div position affected by sibling height

Tags: html, css, position

The red line is the divs container with margin 10px
I want the second div to remain at the blue line whenever a new content is added at the first div, when a new content is added at the first div of course the height expands and this affects the second div to go down which i dont want..
Both div have the following style

```
background-color: #FF694F;
max-width: 400px;
border-radius: 15px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
```

What should i do? i tried everything that i know..
[image: Here's screenshot]

```css
.set {
  background-color: #FF694F;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* height: 100%; */
  position: relative;
  /* max-height: 500px; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#reminder-section-set {
  margin: 10px;
}

.set-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.create-reminder-control {
  margin: 15px;
}

.add-new-reminder {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.add-new-reminder,
.reminder-lists {
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.reminder-lists {
  position: relative;
}

.a-reminder {
  padding: 5px;
}

.save-control {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.save-reminder-button {
  background-color: #FF533D;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 0px #b75050;
}
```

```html
<section id="reminder-section-set">


  <div class="set">
    <div class="set-title">
      <h1 contenteditable="true">Name this reminder</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="create-reminder-control"><button class="add-new-reminder">+ add new</button><input class="create-reminder-value" type="text" placeholder="get something done"></div>
    <div class="reminder-lists">
      <div class="a-reminder">a</div>
      <div class="a-reminder">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="save-control"><button class="save-reminder-button">Save</button></div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="set-title">
      <h1 contenteditable="true">Name this reminder</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="create-reminder-control"><button class="add-new-reminder">+ add new</button><input class="create-reminder-value" type="text" placeholder="get something done"></div>
    <div class="reminder-lists"></div>
    <div class="save-control"><button class="save-reminder-button">Save</button></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Do you want the div's to remain the same height no matter what content is added in the reminder? Or do you want the divs to remain top aligned while they grow in height?

Comment: @StevenLambert yes i want them to remain top aligned

Comment: Does `vertical-align: top` on the `.set` class do what you want?

Comment: OH YES IT DID.. i forgot about this thank you!!